# Strange change detection Ionic 3

Tags: angular, angular2-template, angular2-directives, ionic3

Currently I'm wrapping my Angular4 application with Ionic3. 
During this process I faced with some strange behavior of ChangeDetector.

Here is my header template.

**header.html**

```
<ion-header *ngIf="canDisplayHeader()" [ngStyle]="{'background-color': getColor(backgroundColorMap)}" ion-row>
 <ion-col class="back-button-container">
   <span class="k-icon-back back" [ngStyle]="{'color': getColor(logoColorMap)}"
      (click)="back()" *ngIf="showBackArrow()"></span>
 </ion-col>
 <ion-col class="logo-container" (click)="navigateToDefaultPage()">
   <span class="k-icon-cup_logo logo" [ngStyle]="{'color': getColor(logoColorMap)}"></span>
<div class="title-container">
  <span class="title" [ngStyle]="{'color': getColor(logoColorMap)}">KIOSK</span>
  <span class="office" [ngStyle]="{'color': getColor(fontColorMap)}">on {{getFormattedOfficeName()}}</span>
</div>
</ion-col>
<ion-col class="avatar-container" text-center (click)="changeVisibilityOfLogoutContainer()"
       (clickOutside)="hideLogoutContainerIfVisible($event)">
 <img src="{{employeeResource.getEmployeePicture()}}">
<div class="dropdown-container">
  <span [ngStyle]="{'color': getColor(fontColorMap)}">{{getEmployeeFullName()}}</span>
  <span class="k-icon-caret-down caret"></span>
</div>
<div class="dropdown-menu" *ngIf="isLogoutContainerVisible">
  <div class="menu-option" (click)="navigateToTransactions()">
    <span class="k-icon-coins menu-icon"></span>
    <span>Transactions</span>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <div class="menu-option" (click)="logout()">
    <span class="k-icon-logout menu-icon"></span>
    <span>Logout</span>
  </div>
</div>
</ion-col>
</ion-header>
```

clickOutside directive listens events and checks when to hide dropdown with logout button. It is some kind of toggle. 
It properly record events on every click but `*ngIf="isLogoutContainerVisible"` doesn't detect changes. `isLogoutContainerVisible` value changes but template can't see this change. 
The most weird thing here is that whether template see or not depends on the element I've clicked on. After click on some elements it hides, on another it doesn't and I should manually call `ChangeDetectorRef.detectChanges()`.
There are few places in the system with this problem.

cli packages:

```
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.6.2
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.4.1
@ionic/cli-utils                : 1.7.0
ionic (Ionic CLI)               : 3.7.0
```

global packages:

```
Cordova CLI : 7.0.1
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.3
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.2.3 ios 4.4.0 windows 5.0.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.5.3
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.0.2
Node              : v8.2.1
OS                : Linux 4.10
npm               : 5.3.0
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. 
It's quite simple. 
I just need to wrap all Views in `<ion-content>`, instead of wrapping only main component.